# Use different method for COM- and C#-API

Tags: c#, com

I've got the following class and want to create a c#-API and COM-API from the same class. Because I'm not able to create a List, i want a array in the COM-API.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace myapi
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All), 
        ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDispatch), 
        Guid("AEBE2021-209A-4AEE-9A42-04CB82BEC1CF")]
    class DataProvider: System.Attribute
    {
        int[] data = { 1, 2, 3 };

        [ComVisibleAttribute(false)]
        public List<int> getDataAPI() { //Only Method which should be available for C#-API
            return new List<int>(data);
        }

        [ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
        public int[] getDataCom() //Only Method which should be available for COM
        {
            return data;
        }
    }
}
```

I know that I am able to hide the first method with the `ComVisibleAttribute` for the COM-API. Is there a way to hide or limit the access of the second method for the c#-API? (I mean for the normal build)

Best solution for the user-interface would be to give both methods the same name.

Or am I missing something? is there a better way to bring the List to the Com-Interface.

Comment: You are asking the wrong question, there are plenty of ways to make code work well both in C# and COM without shenanigans like this.  The code looks very fake, it never makes sense to return a mutable List from attribute data.  But an obvious improvement would be to add an indexer.  Works very well in COM as well.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the COM client. If it's jscript for example, you won't be able to use arrays anyway. In this case you'll have to provide all collection methods yourself like GetItem(index), etc.

If the client is VB for example, you should be able to use the old ArrayList instead of an array, or implement a custom collection class.

You can't prevent .NET clients from calling your public methods, but you can use the [EditorBrowsableAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorbrowsableattribute.aspx), like this:

```
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
public int[] getDataCom()
```

In this case, the property will be hidden from auto-completion (unless used from the same assembly). It's better than nothing.